# Docker Registry - Industry Standards

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, artifactory, continuous-deployment

I have been trying to find out if there are any industry standards for docker registry, i.e., how production and staging areas are defined, what version schema is followed etc., but haven't found any doc or blog.
Are there any guidelines or best practices which are followed in docker registry?

P.S. - I'm using jfrog's artifactory.